# Does a virtual network act like an affinity group in azure

Tags: azure

When you add new virtual machines in Azure you can add it directly into a virtual network, but that is the same drop box for the affinity group. Is this then implying that because I am adding in all these VM's into the same virtual network that its going to treat them like they are in the same affinity group?

Thanks in advance for any info. I cant seem to find a straight answer on the windows azure documentation website.

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

A `virtual network` is just a very specific `Affinity Group`.

I really like [this definition of an `Affinity Group`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7916.importance-of-windows-azure-affinity-groups.aspx).  You can see as you read it that it is exactly what a local network (or virtual in our case) is supposed to do.

[Narahari Dogiparthi](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_azure_technical_support_wats_team/archive/2013/02/09/windows-azure-virtual-machines-common-questions.aspx)'s blog states:

> Affinity groups are the way to group the services in your Windows Azure subscription that need to work together in order to achieve optimal performance.
>   When you create an affinity group, it lets Windows Azure know to keep all of the services that belong to your affinity group running at the same data center cluster. For example, if you want to keep the services running your data and your code together, you would specify the same affinity group for those services. That way, when you deploy those services, Windows Azure will locate them in a data center as close to each other as possible. This reduces latency and increases performance, while potentially lowering costs.

[Microsoft's Azure documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156085.aspx) suggests that using both together can give you a `WAN` style network.  Multiple `VLAN`'s connected through one `Affinity Group`.  So you can see that its the same thing, but just another abstraction layer.

[Mark Russinovich](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Speakers/Mark-Russinovich) is also a great guy to follow in this area as well.
[Check out this session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/windowsazure/Learn-2012TechEd-EU/VirtualMachines) where he talks about how Microsoft structures its `virtual networks` in `Azure`. (at ~30:00)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will check out thoes videos right now. Last question, can two virtual networks talk to eachother? A client want's to setup a backend network and front end network. Is it possble? and to be able to control a firewall between them (azure endpoints)?

Comment: I've not tried it, but it should be possible.  let me know if you succeed.  Bummer they put this question on hold.. i thought it was a good one.  Can you still upvote it?

Comment: The only way you can access on virtual network from another on Windows Azure is through the internet